# docker-compose npm install && npm start in entrypoint

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose

I'd like to start 2 containers using docker-compose. One for the database and one for a Node server using the default `node` image on DockerHub. In the Node container, I'd like to mount a local folder that's source controlled as a volume. I've seen many examples where a Dockerfile is created that copies source files into the image and then a `RUN npm install` command is used in the Dockerfile. But that results in a new image being created with the source files in it. In my case, I don't want to save source code files in the Node image. So I'd like the `entrypoint` of the Node container in my docker-compose file to run `npm install` as well as `npm start`, but I can't seem to get that combination to work. Here's my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  server:
    container_name: my_server
    image: node:12.16.1
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ../my-server-files-source-controlled:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
    entrypoint: ["npm", "start"]
    networks:
      - my-network

  db:
    container_name: my_database
    image: postgres
    environment:
      {ommitted}
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

The command above works fine, but when I change the `entrypoint` to include `npm install`, it fails. I've tried the following examples, as well as many others, and they all fail:

```
entrypoint: ["npm", "install", "&&", "npm", "start"]
entrypoint: ["npm install", "npm start"]
entrypoint: "npm install && npm start"
```

It seems like I can have `npm install` or `npm start` in `entrypoint`, but not both. How can get both those commands to work in my docker-compose file?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you want to use multiple commands, you can do so with `bash -c "commands"`:

```
services:
    myservice:
        command: bash -c "npm install && npm start"
```

By the way, in a production deployment, I would suggest using `npm ci` instead of `npm install`. Also consider using the `--only=prod` and `--no-audit` flags (depending on your setup).

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! So use `entrypoint` for a single command and `command` complex ones? I'm just getting into docker and still trying to grasp all of the options. 

Comment: `entrypoint:` and `command:` get concatenated together to form a single command.  Both parts are optional; typically you'd specify them via the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` lines in your Dockerfile, and not override them in the `docker-compose.yml` file.